# Winforms: Which event to fire? combobox.selectedindexchanged OR bindingsource.currentchanged

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, event-handling, bindingsource

Assume we have a `Combobox` in a winforms application which its items bound to a `Bindingsource`.

I need to fire an event when the user changes the selected item in the `combobox`.

Should I handle the `combobox.selectedindexchanged` event or `bindingsource.currentchanged` event. Which is better in case of performance or anything else?

I've searched a lot to find an article or something about it, but can't find something straight and clear. I appreciate any suggestion or workaround.

**UPDATE**

I need to call a function base on the selected object `ID` after user select an Item from `combobox`. (`ID` is accessible from both `Combobox1.SelectedValue` and `bindingSource1.Current.ID`).  In this case which event shouldI choose?

Comment: I believe there shouldnt be performance difference between those 2 events, but `combobox.SelectedIndexChanged` event feels more natural in such situation, doesnt it?

Comment: [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Personally, I think you should choose the event that matches what you actually need to do with it. If your response is _data_-oriented, go with the `BindingSource`, if it's something you need to do with the UI, go with the `ComboBox`. That way, the event handler can remain with the component where it's actually relevant. But this assumes you've done a good job keeping your UI code separate from business logic in the first place, something most Winforms programmers fail to do.

Comment: I need to call a function base on the selected object `ID` after user select an Item from `combobox`. (`ID` is accessible from both `Combobox1.SelectedValue` and `bindingSource1.Current.ID`).  In this case which event shouldI choose?

Comment: I am getting to know it should be better to use `Combobox.selectedIndexChanded` event, because I am interacting with a user and looking for a responce from UI. Although here the events do the same for me, but `bindingsource.currentchanged` event can be used in case I wanted to track the current object changes from anywhere like a list change, not exactly the UI. Its better to use combobox event here.

Comment: If you need to call an event when the combobox is at a value then do it in the Business Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all, I am getting to know it should be better to use `Combobox.SelectedIndexChanded` event, because I am interacting with a user and looking for a response from UI. Although here the events do the same for me, but `Bindingsource.CurrentChanged` event can be used in case I wanted to track the current object changes from anywhere like a list change or something, not exactly the UI. Its better to use `combobox` events here I believe.

Answer (score 0):

If a ComboBox is bound to a BindingSource you usually leave it at that. If you do need to tap into events you're better off creating more properties in the Business Object. For example say you want to disable a button if the combobox is Index Value == 0, simply create a property in the Business Object that the Enabled property of the Button is bound to, eg:

```
public virtual bool IsFunctionEnabled
{
  get { return (An_Items_SelectedIndex > 0); }
}
```

If you really need to do stuff in the ComboBox's selected index change event I would lean towards doing it in the Presentation Tier as I don't recommend mucking with binding source controls or their events.

The best solution is handling everything in your Business Objects and binding your controls via BindingSources. Doing any logic in the Presentation Tier makes it hard to test and changing anything in the BindingSources add a lot of testing.

Comment: The above is a decent response to an overly broad, primarily opinion-based question (i.e. one that shouldn't have been answered in the first place). That said, I would disagree with the _specifics_ above. I.e. your business logic shouldn't care that there's a button at all, never mind have a property named `IsButtonEnabled`. The business logic should concern itself with UI-agnostic commands, where commands can be enabled/disabled, and the UI then enables/disables appropriate parts accordingly (buttons and menu items, primarily).

Comment: _"...simply create a property in the Business Object (BO) that the Enabled property of the Button...(shows a property named IsFunctionEnabled that refers to An_Items_SelectedIndex )...The best solution is handling everything in your Business Objects "_ - Disagree. The BO should not care about the UI

Comment: I believe this is not that complicated to be handled in BL. just a simple function call. I just confused which event to choose.

Comment: Agree guys, I changed it to be more UI agnostic and obviously when I say handle everything I mean business logic. Issue with this question is OP wants to tap into control/Ui specific behavior so that's why I initially gave UI example. Hope this clears any confusion

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to handle event when end user selects any item in UI then you should go with `combobox.selectedindexchanged` because `bindingsource.currentchanged` can be triggered for number reasons such as mentioned here on MSDN blog, [BindingSource.CurrentChanged Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.currentchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) so in case, you need to handle an event for any of the reason mentioned in MSDN then it will unnecessarily go through logic you might have coded for selection change event. Your code should be specific, while handling events.

Comment: Are you saying that if the `BindingSource.Current` property changes, the bound `ComboBox` won't have _its_ current selection changed to match?